# Ubuntu 18.04 Only Boots Successfully from Recovery Mode

Tags: boot, 18.04

[image: Screenshot]

My install of Ubuntu 18.04 only boots successfully through recovery mode. If I attempt to boot normally, it runs for a while, and then hangs up. I'm not sure which part of this is the error.

```
BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 00000000000008  
IP: _raw_spin_lock+0x10/0x30  
PGD 0 P4D 0  
Oops: 0002 [#2] SMP NOPTI  
Modules linked in: lp(+) parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_g  
CPU: 0 PID: 8 Comm: rcu_sched Tained: G     D       4.15.0-3  
Hardware name: To be filled by O.E.M. To be filled by O.E.M./X370  
RIP: 0010:_raw_spin_lock+0x10/0x30  
RSP: 0018:ffff9eca00c87cc0 EFLAGS: 00010046  
RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0206800000000000 RCX: 0000000000000000  
RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: ffff8e09969f0000 RDI: 0000000000000008  
RBP: ffff9eca00c87cc0 R08: 0000000000000235 R09: 0000000000000001  
R10: ffff9eca00c87d40 R11: 000000000000022c R12: ffff8e099ee15b30  
R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000000020 R15: 0000000000005000  
FS: 00000000000000000(0000) GS: ffff8e099ee00000(0000) knlGS:00000000  
CS: 0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033  
CR2: 0000000000000008 CR3: 000000021104a00 CR4: 00000000003406f0  
Call Trace:  
__switch_to_xtra+0x2e0/0x350  
__switch_to_+0x494/0x500  
? __switch_to_+0x494/0x500  
__schedule+0x291/0x8a0  
schedule+0x2x/0x80  
schedule_timeout_0x15d/0x350  
? __next_timer_interrupt_0xe0/0xe0  
rcu_gp_kthread+0x53a/0x960  
kthread+0x121/0x140  
? rcu_note_context_switch+0x150/0x150  
? kthread_create_worker_on_cpu+0x70/0x70  
ret_from_fork+0x22/0x40  
Code: ff 01 00 00 75 06 48 89 d8 5b 5d c3 e8 7a 6a 74 ff 48 89 d8 5b  
RIP: raw_spin_lock+0x10/0x30 RSP:ffff9eca00c87cc0  
CR2: 00000000000000000  
---[end trace 7f3902c3ccbb91eb]---
```

Comment: Can you please rotate that image!

Comment: Sorry, it's fixed now.